# processing sketch not rendering in chrome..?

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas, processing.js

I'm using canvas for integrating processing sketch into webpage, it's working perfectly fine in firefox but not in chrome. Any idea what could have gone wrong.I'm simply using processing.js and canvas with processing.pde sketch. sorry if this doesn't qualify to be asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Processing.js typically works very well with Chrome. Are you using any other scripts on the page that might be conflicting with Processing?

It would help if you could post a link to the page you're working on.